# Use systemd-home on a live cd system

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, live-usb, home, livecd

I'm configuring an `archiso` profile to correctly implement an user managed by `systemd-home` in its generated iso. User's home directory doesn't need to be encrypted.

How can I do that?

**PS:** it seems there is no `systemd-home` tag.

**PPS:** I guess the answer to this question also answers *how to easily migrate an user managed from `systemd-home` to a new system?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you've created the `user` user with `UID` and `GID` `60101` and that you're running your live cd with the standard user structure in place.

##### Prerequisites

Users managed by `systemd-home` need site-specific configurations which
depend on the system's `machine-id`. Since you're using a live cd system
you need to set a static `machine-id` first.

To do so, add the `systemd.machine_id=<your_machine_id>`
option to kernel boot parameters. You can get a system's `machine-id` with

```
systemd-machine-id-setup --print
```

**NB:** `machine-id`s should be considered "confidential", and must not be exposed in untrusted environments, in particular on the network.

##### Setup

1. Enable the `systemd-homed` service (on a live cd it implies
   to setup the correct symlinks for the associated services in `/etc/systemd/system`).
2. Set `systemd-home` configuration file so that it won't create an encrypted home:

   ```
   /etc/systemd/homed.conf
   ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
   DefaultStorage=directory
   ```
3. Remove any `user` entry from

   - `/etc/passwd`
   - `/etc/gshadow`
   - `/etc/shadow`
   - `/etc/group`
4. Move user directory from `/home/user` to `/home/user.saved`
5. Let `user` be managed by `systemd-home`:

   ```
   homectl create user --uid=60101 \
                       --real-name="Standard Computer User" \
                       --shell=/usr/bin/zsh
   ```
6. Move old home over new home:

   ```
   homectl with foobar -- rsync -aHAXv \
                                --remove-source-files \
                                /home/foobar.saved/ .
   ```
7. Check everything has been correctly passed over.
8. Copy

   - `/etc/systemd/homed.conf`
   - `/home/user.homedir`
   - `/var/lib/systemd/home`

   back to the `airootfs` of your `archiso` profile.

#### References

- [machine-id](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html)
- [Converting Existing Users to systemd-homed](https://systemd.io/CONVERTING_TO_HOMED/)
- [Users, Groups, UIDs and GIDs on systemd Systems](https://systemd.io/UIDS-GIDS/)
- [JSON User Records](https://systemd.io/USER_RECORD/)
- [systemd-homed - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-homed)